# Multiple 'Just x' for 'case maybeVal of' in haskell

Tags: haskell, switch-statement, option-type

Do multiple 'Just' cases work in haskell, and in order eg. in

```
findElement :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> Maybe Int
findElement element list = case (listToMaybe list) of
                             Nothing -> Nothing
                             Just element -> Just 0
                             Just _ -> Just (1 + (fromMaybe 0 (findElement element (tail list))))
```

Only one of Just cases seem to work (which-ever is placed first).
Expected outcome is-

```
> findElement 4 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
Just 3
> findElement 3 [5,6,4,7,8,0]
Nothing
> findElement 4 []
Nothing
> findElement 'o' "Hello world"
Just 4
> findElement 'x' ""
Nothing
```

Comment: Conceptually it makes more sense to just return a list in that case, since an empty list can be seen as a `Nothing`, and a non-empty lists all the indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not work in that way, you need a guard like this:

```
findElement element list = 
   case (listToMaybe list) of
      Nothing               -> ...
      Just e | e == element -> ...
      Just _                -> ...
```

The problem is: every variable occurring in patterns gets bound to the matching value. If you write `Just element` this does *not* refer to the previous variable `element` but introduces a *new* local variable instead, must as `e` in my code above.

So, pattern matching on `Just element` is very similar to

```
 findElement element list = 
    let element = ...
    in ...
```

In the last line, the previous variable `element` gets "shadowed" by the later binding.

To avoid this mistake, I strongly suggest to turn on warnings with `-Wall`: that would point out the dangerous shadowings.